# Run shortcode at the end of post content / before comments

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to use do_shortcode in single.php. Despite the fact I put it after

```
<?php get_template_part('content'); ?>
```

the shortcode is executed at the beginning of the page. What I'm trying to achieve is running the shortcode as soon as the user reaches a specific part of the page (let's say the end of the post, just before comments).

What should I add to the code to make it happen?

The code I'm inserting is:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[EPSB]'.<div class="fb-like" data-width="200" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>.'[/EPSB]'); ?>
```

Thanks in advance. Sorry for the vague description, I'm new to wordpress coding.

Comment: just out of curiosity: what's `[EPSB]` tag(?) is supposed to do? what language or expression or... is that?

Comment: @AlexMorrise thanks! have a link or something? hard to find anything through all the movie results on google...

Comment: @webeno it's a shortcode for End Page Slidebox plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[EPSB]'.<div class="fb-like" data-width="200" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>.'[/EPSB]'); ?>
```

Should be this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[EPSB]<div class="fb-like" data-width="200" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>[/EPSB]'); ?>
```